# ERROR 1: PROJ: tmerc: Invalid latitude

Tags: raster, qgis-3

Im trying to warp(reproject) a raster layer to EPSG 4647 and keep getting the Error above. It works when I'm just right-clicking on the layer and set the CRS (it moves to the right position). But in a further working step Im getting errors and I think its because the crs is not "really" set. So I want to warp it. Any suggestions what could be the mistake?

[image]

In a next working step I want to clip the Raster layer by a vector layer and I'm getting the following error which I thought maybe results from a wrong CRS.

[image]

Comment: If it appears in the right place then it must have the right CRS set, and have the right coordinate values for that CRS, and so no need warping to that CRS. If you are trying to warp it to that CRS, what CRS are you warping *from*? Because the signs are that it already *is* in the 4647 CRS (impossible to tell without your data file or a view of all the metadata...)

Comment: When I'm opening a new project the raster layers CRS is the default CRS 4326 but I get the same error when trying to warp it. I edited my question with more information, maybe that helps..

Comment: In what CRS is your cutline shapefile? It may be that because of mixed CRS gdalwarp gets advice to crop the output into very small extent, less than one pixel, and that leads to an error.

Comment: If its in the right place then there's no need to warp it. Why are you trying?

Comment: Okay so I started from scratch and put the DEM together from xyz files and in the end it now worked but only after reprojecting the layer again, even if it was in the right location before.. So it seems like the CRS was not really recognized before.